# Spooling Directory Source Stuck In Exception [Serializer Has Been Closed]

Tags: hdfs, flume

I am using spooling directory source of cloudera flume with HDFS as a sink.
I am facing **Serializer Has Been Closed** error.
I am only copying files one at a time and this occurs after I copy the first file using **scp**

My agent is as follows :

```
    agentaccesscombined.sources=spooldir-accesscombinedsource
    agentaccesscombined.sinks=hdfs-accesscombinedsink
    agentaccesscombined.channels=chaccesscombined

    # flume spooldir source
    agentaccesscombined.sources.spooldir-accesscombinedsource.type=spooldir
    agentaccesscombined.sources.spooldir-accesscombinedsource.spoolDir=/var/spoolAccessCombinedDir
    agentaccesscombined.sources.spooldir-accesscombinedsource.ignorePattern=\\w.*.filepart
    agentaccesscombined.sources.spooldir-accesscombinedsource.deletePolicy=immediate
    agentaccesscombined.sources.spooldir-accesscombinedsource.fileSuffix=.SPOOL
    agentaccesscombined.sources.spooldir-accesscombinedsource.fileHeader=true
    agentaccesscombined.sources.spooldir-accesscombinedsource.bufferMaxLineLength=70000
    agentaccesscombined.sources.spooldir-accesscombinedsource.bufferMaxLines=10000
    agentaccesscombined.sources.spooldir-accesscombinedsource.batchSize=1000
    agentaccesscombined.sources.spooldir-accesscombinedsource.fileHeaderKey=file

    #flume hdfs-sink
    agentaccesscombined.sinks.hdfs-accesscombinedsink.type=hdfs
    agentaccesscombined.sinks.hdfs-accesscombinedsink.hdfs.path=hdfs://cldx-1044:1200:8020/flumeOut_spoolDir_access_combined
    agentaccesscombined.sinks.hdfs-accesscombinedsink.hdfs.rollSize=12553700
    agentaccesscombined.sinks.hdfs-accesscombinedsink.hdfs.rollCount=12553665
    agentaccesscombined.sinks.hdfs-accesscombinedsink.hdfs.rollInterval=100000
    agentaccesscombined.sinks.hdfs-accesscombinedsink.hdfs.fileType=DataStream
    agentaccesscombined.sinks.hdfs-accesscombinedsink.hdfs.writeFormat=Text
    agentaccesscombined.sinks.hdfs-accesscombinedsink.round = true
    agentaccesscombined.sinks.hdfs-accesscombinedsink.roundValue=50
    agentaccesscombined.sinks.hdfs-accesscombinedsink.roundUnit=minute
    agentaccesscombined.sinks.hdfs-accesscombinedsink.hdfs.idleTimeout=5

    #flume channel 
    agentaccesscombined.channels.chaccesscombined.type=file
    agentaccesscombined.channels.chaccesscombined.capacity=1000000
    agentaccesscombined.channels.chaccesscombined.transactionCapacity = 1000
    agentaccesscombined.channels.chaccesscombined.checkpointInterval=30000
    agentaccesscombined.channels.chaccesscombined.maxFileSize=2146435071
    agentaccesscombined.channels.chaccesscombined.minimumRequiredSpace=524288000
    agentaccesscombined.channels.chaccesscombined.keep-alive=30
    agentaccesscombined.channels.chaccesscombined.write-timeout=30
    agentaccesscombined.channels.chaccesscombined.checkpoint-timeout=6000
    agentaccesscombined.channels.chaccesscombined.checkpointDir=/tmp/flume/java/checkpoint_accesscombined
    agentaccesscombined.channels.chaccesscombined.dataDirs=/tmp/flume/java/data_accesscombined


agentaccesscombined.sources.spooldir-accesscombinedsource.channels=chaccesscombined
agentaccesscombined.sinks.hdfs-accesscombinedsink.channel=chaccesscombined
```

If I am copying file using **winscp** it is working fine but not using **scp**.
Please help me out.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

To fix the immediate problem restart your flume agent.
Then use a method of copying your file that is atomic.

The spooling directory source *requires* that the file not change once it has started reading it. If the file changes then it will log an error message and start producing errors like the one you show above.

`cp` is not atomic. I don't know about `scp`, etc. Perhaps copy to a temp directory and then use `mv`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use winscp upload your file to a temp dir and then move to the flume monitoring dir via "mv". mv operation is atomic. You may need inotify the do the automation.